# Adding strings when using echo in foreach PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am using foreach to display certain values from my db in laravel php. However, when i run multiple foreach statements, the values come as single values like "100.00 200.00". However, I would like the values to be an added string like "300.00" after the foreach statements. My foreach statements look as follows:

```
@php
foreach($cash_sales as $cs){
  if( $ledgers->id == $cs->dr_ledger){
    echo number_format($cs->amount, 2);
  };
};      

foreach($oprefund_credit_cr as $op){
  if( $receivable->id == $op->ledger_code){
    echo number_format($op->amount, 2);
  };
};
@endphp
```

I want the values to be conctatenated using by adding them. Is there any way in which I could achieve what I want? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Will you get the first value like in three digits "100.00". Please confirm

Comment: use explode function and split the two values, and add all the values

Comment: Yes! I am accurately getting the values as required. I just need to find a way of adding them @Muthusamy

Comment: then use the second command

Comment: Could you give me a link to an example @Muthusamy

Comment: <?php

$values = "100.00 200.00";
$test = explode(" ", $values);
$val = 0;
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
 # code...
 $val = $val + $value;
}

echo $val;

?>

Comment: please check the above my comment @jptl431

Comment: I am trying to find a way to explode the values, but what I cant get is that I don't have a fixed variable for each ledger i.e id. I am getting the ids from if statements, thereby making it difficult for me to run the explode function @Muthusamy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185184/discussion-between-muthusamy-and-jptl431).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try below solution. If you have a string then explode before operation. See below

```
@php
$tempSum = array();
$cash_sales = explode(',', $cash_sales);
$oprefund_credit_cr = explode(',', $oprefund_credit_cr)

foreach($cash_sales as $csKey => $cs){
  if( $ledgers->id == $cs->dr_ledger){
    $tempSum[$csKey][] = $cs->amount;
  };
};

foreach($oprefund_credit_cr as $opKey => $op){
  if( $receivable->id == $op->ledger_code){
    $tempSum[$opKey][] = $op->amount;
  };
};

if(!empty($tempSum))
{   
    foreach($tempSum as $temp_result) {
        if( !empty($temp_result) && count($temp_result) > 0 ){
            $sum = 0;
            foreach($temp_result as $temp) {
                $sum += $temp;
            }
            echo number_format($sum, 2);
        };
    };  
}
@endphp
```

Comment: I have tried this. It gives me totally different values from what I desire, but the idea seems to be valid

Comment: @jptl431 can you please give me the value of $cash_sales and $oprefund_credit_cr? so i can test and verify?

Comment: `Pharmacy income
18,941,449.0743,789,775.84`
`Pathology income
4,500.0020,175,142.15`

Comment: The values are separate after the 2 decimal points. For pharmacy income, 1 value is coming from cash_sales and the other one from oprefund_credit_cr. The same is happening with the pathology income. I need to add the two values to give me one value which is a sum of both @Nirali

Comment: I do not have a variable that stores the different strings, I am just echoing what I get from the db

Comment: Is there another method where I can give you a clearer view of my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185188/discussion-between-nirali-and-jptl431).

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question right, store the intermediate result in a variable and print it at the end.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($cash_sales as $cs){
  if( $ledgers->id == $cs->dr_ledger){
    sum += $cs->amount; 

  };
};      

foreach($oprefund_credit_cr as $op){
  if( $receivable->id == $op->ledger_code){
    echo number_format($op->amount, 2);
    $sum+=$op->amount;
  };
};
echo number_format($sum, 2);
```

EDIT:

This should hold individual sums per ledger

```
$result = [];

foreach($cash_sales as $cs){
  if( $ledgers->id == $cs->dr_ledger)
  {
       $key = 'cash_sales_'.$cs->dr_ledger;
       if (empty($result[$key]) $result[$key] = 0; 
       $result[$key] += $cs->amount; 

  };
};      

foreach($oprefund_credit_cr as $op){
  if( $receivable->id == $op->ledger_code){
    $key = 'oprefund_credit_cr_'.$op->ledger_code;
    if (empty($result[$key]) $result[$key] = 0; 
    $result[$key] += $cs->amount; 
  };
};


foreach($result as $key=>$value)
{
    echo sprintf("%s: %s", $key, number_format($value, 2));
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that I get only one value at the end. I have multiple ledgers with different values. If I initialize only one variable, then it will give me an accumulated sum, which I am already deriving. What I intend to get is sum of each individual "echo"

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain 2 variables, one for Dr and another for Cr. Then Sum them up and `echo` it only once after the loop is over.

```
@php
$sumDr = 0;
foreach($cash_sales as $cs){
  if( $ledgers->id == $cs->dr_ledger){
    $sumDr += $cs->amount;
  };
};

echo 'Dr Ledger=' . number_format($sumDr, 2);

$sumCr = 0;
foreach($oprefund_credit_cr as $op){
  if( $receivable->id == $op->ledger_code){
    $sumCr += $op->amount;
  };
};

echo 'Cr Ledger=' . number_format($sumCr, 2);
@endphp
```

Comment: I have tried this. It works well when it comes to getting a sum of all the values from the database. However, what I want is sum for each individual ledger. For instance, the `cash_sales` has multiple ledgers and also the oprefund credit has multiple ledgers with the same id as those of the cash_sales. When the values are displayed, e.g `cash  100.00 200.00` `bank 400.00 300.00` What I need is something like `cash 300.00` `bank 700.00` etc

Comment: It's little unclear. Can you please post your current output and expected output more specifically?

Comment: So for instance, I have a table `cash_sales` which has multiple ids representing multiple ledgers. I also have a table `oprefund_credit_cr` which has multiple ids representing multiple ledgers. In my view, I need to display each ledger with the corresponding id from the table. There are instances when a ledger is both in the cash_sales and oprefund_credit_cr. When I run the foreach statement, it checks against the id and displays a result. When there is a value in both the tables corresponding to the same id, then the values for both the tables are displayed. @Samir

Comment: <?php
$values = "100.00 200.00";
$test = explode(" ", $values);
$val = 0;
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
 $val = $val + $value;
}
echo $val;

?>